# How to add mapping fields when indexing data with Elasticsearch and Nestjs

Tags: typescript, elasticsearch, mapping, nestjs

I'm building a NestJS app using [ElasticSearch](https://github.com/nestjs/elasticsearch). I've been able to insert some data with the Client wrapped from [oficial elasticsearch lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@elastic/elasticsearch). Since my data will have specific fields where one of them will be an object (where this object could have multiples field, object included), I want to map the whole fields from the data that will be added to this index.
At this moment my code looks like:

```
let insertedData = await this.elasticSearch.index({index: 'products', body:{
            name: 'Window',
            material: 'glass',
            observation: {
                type: '1'
            }
     }})
```

The mapping will be: name: string, material: string, observation: flattened. I couldn't find a way that shows how to map the data using the Client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching with some posts and blog articles,the right way to do it is using:
[indices.create](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-js/16.x/api-indices-create-7-1.html) then, you need to use [putMapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-js/16.x/api-indices-putmapping-7-1.html). The code will look like:

```
this.elasticSearch.indices.create({index: 'products'});
this.elasticSearch.indices.putMapping({
                index: 'products',
                body:{
                    properties:{
                        name:     { type: 'text' },
                        material:    { type: 'text' },
                        observation:        { type: 'flattened' },

                    }
                }
            });
```